# slideToggle() doesn't extend mobile menu on Chrome mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got problems with my mobile menu on Chrome mobile browser:

I have fixed menu in a header, header has height of 55px.
Each link in menu has 50px.

On slideToggle() my menu turns from display:none to display: block and z-index to 99.

```
$("#mobileMenu").hide();
$(".toggleMobile").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $("#mobileMenu").slideToggle();
});

#mobileMenu {
    display: block;
    z-index: 99;
}

.toggleMobile {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 380px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

On firebug and chrome browser it works like it should, on .toggleMobile click my #mobileMenu shows. However when I use mobile device, when I click .toggleMobile my #mobileMenu shows up to certain point which is 55px (header height).

Sorry for not providing jsfiddle, it would be difficult for me to provide it.

Do You have any idea why my menu doesn't show up correctly on mobile chrome browser but it does on normal one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a height $("#mobileMenu").height(200).slideToggle();

Comment: That could be nice solution, I'll check it as soon as possible :) However I think overflow:hidden which I found somewhere in main CSS could be a problem.

Comment: It worked when I removed overflow:hidden but for trying I'll accept an answer :) thanks